# Audio In and Out [line In]

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Hello I just installed ubuntu on hardware for the first time I've used it and other OS's in VM for a while with my rig when I was on windows I have a laptop beside me that I like to take audio in from the line in on the back that was redirected out into my headphones on my pc

Audio from laptop > into pc > out headphones / Monitor speakers

I tried to use a module called module loopback but no luck it just repeated my Mic causing an echo

Sorry if this is a rather silly question
tried to look for a way to configure the module but couldn't find much

Comment: If you got to your Sound settings and go to the input tab, do you get any readings on the "Input level" indicator? Make sure you have the correct input device selected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the loopback module. Undo all of that. Go to a terminal and type:

```
alsamixer
```

Use the arrows to move over to `Line`, press `M` to unmute. Then `Up` to increase the volume to the top level you can choose while it's in the green (44 for my machine). Lastly, arrow over to `Loopback`, and press `Up` to enable. This will create a loopback channel at a hardware level. Works much better.

*Edit*
To provide a bit more context, this is the best method for a number of reasons:

- **Audio volume is controlled separately on each machine:** While the volume of the subordinate machine is "based" on the volume set in ALSA mixer, since it's hardware level when you adjust the volume on the main computer, it doesn't impact the subordinate, and visa-versa.
- **Bluetooth works independently:** If you connect a Bluetooth headset to the main computer, the audio from the main computer will go through the BT, but the audio from the subordinate computer will continue to pass through the line-out to the speakers. Subsequently the same is true for connecting a Bluetooth device to the subordinate machine.
- **Front panel connectors still work:** Same as BT.
- **Zero latency:** Probably most importantly for videos/gaming, it's hardware pass-through, so there won't be any latency in the audio signal.